# Restrict typescript class methods implementing interface

Tags: javascript, typescript, class

Currently if I create a class that implements an interface, the class created will all methods not included in the interface. Here's an example:

```
interface ExampleTypes {
  alpha();
}

class Example implements ExampleTypes {
  alpha () {
    return true
  }
  beta () {
    return true
  }
}
```

I am looking for a way to restrict the methods a given class can have.

This is something I also tried:

```
class ExampleSource {
  alpha () {
    return true
  }
}

class Example implements Partial<ExampleSource> {
  alpha () {
    return true
  }
  beta () {
    return true
  }
}
```

And this:

```
class ExampleSource {
  alpha () {
    return true
  }
}

class Example implements ExampleSource {
  alpha () {
    return true
  }
  beta () {
    return true
  }
}
```

Which is unintuitive. I'd like `beta` to not be allowed in `Example`.

This is the functionality that works but using a function and not a class:

```
interface ExampleType {
  alpha?();
  beta?();
}
```

This is value:

```
function Example(): ExampleType {
  return {
    alpha: () => true,
  };
}
```

This throws a typescript error:

```
function Example(): ExampleType {
  return {
    alpha: () => true,
    meow: () => true,
  };
}
```

Ideally I can have this same functionality but with classes.

Comment: Why?  That's just not how OOP Programming works, especially considering the SOLID principles.

Comment: I suppose that is something that you could do in the constructor function. Maybe have a model that a given instance of the class should conform to, and have the constructor strip everything else off that doesn't fit the model. This could be done dynamically by passing in different models that represent a subset of the functions/properties of your class

Comment: there is [no thing like `final`](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9264) in TS

Comment: @skyboyer Not sure final is what the OP is looking for. They want TypeScript to enforce a strict definition of a class by using another interface. No additional properties should exist on the class that do not exist in the interface.

Comment: @mhodges Yes I would like to have many classes that implement a true Partial from a common source (interface or another class) where the classes cannot have any extra methods, only methods defined from the source.

Comment: Added some more updates on things i've tried.

Comment: TS does not have exact types, so this is generally not going to be possible. Extra stuff is allowed to satisfy a type. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @ThomasReggi: Is it actually important that the *classes* don't have extra members?  Or do you want to restrict *uses* of those classes?  Because you can do the latter by just upcasting to `Partial<ExampleSource>`.  But to actually try to restrict what methods a class contains is really suspect.

Comment: @MarkPeters Yes I would like the classes not not have extra members. The uses of those classes is not relevant to this question.

Comment: So inferring from that, that implies that it's the runtime members of the prototype that you care about, not satisfying the type checker.  If that's the case are you sure types/interfaces are the right path here?  After all they're mostly only relevant in a static context, at compile time.  Vs an approach like @mhodges suggests, where you inspect the object at runtime.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It's an odd request, since having extra methods won't stop you from using the class as if they weren't there.  TypeScript doesn't really have a lot of support for excluding extra properties or methods from types; that is, there's currently no direct support for *exact types* as requested in [microsoft/TypeScript#12936](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936).

Luckily you can sort of get this behavior by [making](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936#issuecomment-368244671) a self-referential [conditional](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html), [mapped](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) type:

```
type Exactly<T, U> = { [K in keyof U]: K extends keyof T ? T[K] : never };
```

If you declare that a type `U` is `Exactly<T, U>`, it will make sure `U` matches `T`, and that any extra properties are of type `never`.  Self-referential/recursive/circular types don't always compile, but in this case you're only referring to `keyof U` inside the definition of `U`, which is allowed.

Let's try it:

```
interface ExampleTypes {
  alpha(): boolean; // adding return type
}

// notice the self-reference here
class Example implements Exactly<ExampleTypes, Example> {
  // okay
  alpha() {
    return true;
  }

  // error!  Type '() => boolean' is not assignable to type 'never'.
  beta() {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Looks like it works!